# Display friendlier names for files loaded using FilenameFilter

Tags: java, android

My directory on sdcard has only four files as follows:

```
sdcard/myfolder/15052013/15052013.tpm
sdcard/myfolder/loek/loek.doc
sdcard/myfolder/Android/Android.txt
sdcard/myfolder/Input_Output/Input_Output.htm
```

I use the following code to get two particular files (`loek` and `Input_Output`) from a directory and then display the filenames on a Dialog:

```
button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.swap);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            loadFileList();
            showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
            }
    }); 

private void loadFileList() {
       if(mPath.exists()) {           
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {                
                return !filename.startsWith("15052013") && !filename.startsWith("Android");                            
            }
        };        
        mFileList = mPath.list(filter);           
    }
    else 
    {
        mFileList= new String[0];
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
    switch(id) {
        case DIALOG_LOAD_FILE:
            builder.setTitle("Choose one");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.dictionary);
            if(mFileList == null) {
                Log.e(MAIN_TAG, "Showing file picker before loading the file list");
                dialog = builder.create();                                         
                return dialog;
            }
            builder.setItems(mFileList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mDBFile = mDBList.items.get(which);                     
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    menuMain();                     
                }
            });
            break;
    }    
    dialog = builder.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.y = 90;
    //params.x = 0;
    params.height = 500;
    params.width = 400;
    params.dimAmount=0.f;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    return dialog;      
}
```

The filenames are successfully loaded and displayed on the dialog, but they are all "raw" filenames. I want the filenames to appear like:

```
loek ==> Information about Mr Loek Basten
Input_Output ==> Differences between the In-Flow and Out-Flow
```

Now it comes to my question: **How can I display friendlier names for these files?**

I wonder if you can help regarding my code? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are getting at the moment?

Comment: Thanks, the dialog shows: `loek` on the first row and `Input_Output` on the second row.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html) where the properties file looks something like this:

```
loek.doc=Information about Mr Loek Basten
Input_Output.htm=Differences between the In-Flow and Out-Flow
```

That way you can add more files and their descriptions without changing the source code.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: A ResourceBundle (as linked above) enables you to have a simple text file which has the file ending `.properties` which can then be read within the program. So for example, you could call it `DescriptionBundle.properties` and have an object `ResourceBundle descriptions = ResourceBundle.getBundle("DescriptionBundle", currentLocale);` in your code. Then you can access the various descriptions with `descriptions.getString(mFileList[i])` (where `i` is the entry of which you want to know the key).

Comment: Thanks, but have looked into this but couldn't figure out what to do.